# Adjust spacing between a section title and the first contained cell

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

In my day-to-day work with Mathematica I use a stylesheet I have derived from Mathematica's default stylesheet. One modification I would like to make to my stylesheet is to reduce the spacing between a section title and the first cell inside the section. This is *not* controlled by the CellMargins option. Is there another notebook option that can be set to reduce this gap?

Comment: The spacing *is* controlled by the cell margin --Try this: `CellMargins->{{27, Inherited}, {0, 34}}`. What makes you say that it isn't?

Comment: bear in mind that the total spacing between a section cell and the next cell is the sum of the bottom margin for the section cell and the top margin for the subsequent cell.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch -- it's a bit embarrassing, but I reached my conclusion that it was not controlled by CellMargins because I thought the margins list went {{left,right},{top,bottom}} and not {{left,right},{bottom, top}}. I was changing the wrong list element and thus not seeing the result I expected.

Comment: we've all made mistakes like that. I've made worse. Just bear in mind though that for a consistent spacing you will need to have the same cell type (e.g. subsection) following your section cell because most cells types are configured by default to have different top margins. (and therefore the spacing between section->input will be different from section->text etc.)

Comment: This is a good question though, with a useful answer. Do you want to add it as an answer rather than a comment Mike?

Comment: Thanks to Mike I now have my stylesheet cell spacing adjusted to get the look I want.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Honeychurch .  Now I can "at will" control the spacing between any two specific cells, which is nice when Input/Output cells are being incorporated into a "paragraph."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by Mike Honeychurch:

The spacing is controlled by the cell margin.Try this:

```
CellMargins->{{27, Inherited}, {0, 34}}
```

Bear in mind that the total spacing between a section cell and the next cell is the sum of the bottom margin for the section cell and the top margin for the subsequent cell.

For a consistent spacing you will need to have the same cell type (e.g. subsection) following your section cell because most cells types are configured by default to have different top margins. (and therefore the spacing between section->input will be different from section->text etc.)